# how can I schedule a custom script to run whenever I restart a service

Tags: linux, systemd, tomcat

I wish to know how can I schedule a custom script to run whenever I restart a service.

My use case is that I have to run several commands whenever I restart my Tomcat Service. I want to know if there is a way I can write a script and schedule it to run whenever I restart the Tomcat service.

I have setup the tomcat script as a systemd service. I am using Cent OS 7 x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have tomcat, but it should be the same as for apache, which I tried as follows (you probably only need to replace httpd by tomcat everywhere).

Simply create an new systemd `httpd.service` file in `/etc` which includes and overrides part of the one in `/lib`. 
For example, create `/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service` to contain

```
.include /lib/systemd/system/httpd.service
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/home/meuh/myscripttorun  some pre args here
ExecStartPost=/home/meuh/myscripttorun some post args here
```

Any `ExecStartPre` lines will be executed before the apache `ExecStart` line, and similarly any `ExecStartPost` will run after apache has started.